# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function locale() on a non-object

Tags: plugins, php, 500-internal-error

It is all started after I updated some of the plugins in my Wordpress site.

Right now I'm getting an Http Internal 500 Error when I try to access WordPress dashboard.

Error at my error log file in File Manager.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function locale() on a non-object in /wp-content/themes/my_theme/lib/custom.php at line 25.
```

my custom.php file looks like this.

```
24. global $sitepress;
25. setlocale(LC_TIME, $sitepress->locale() . '.UTF-8');
26. $_SESSION['date_format'] = (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr') ? 'le %e %B %G' : '%B %e, %G';
```

Any suggestions on this issue!!

Comment: clearly `$sitepress` isn't an object as expected, can you find out what `$sitepress` actually contains and its data type?

Answer (score 3):

`$sitepress` is a global set by WPML, IIRC. Change your line 25 as follows:

```
if(isset($sitepress) && is_object($sitepress)) {
  setlocale(LC_TIME, $sitepress->locale() . '.UTF-8');
}
```

As a general rule you shouldn't assume in a theme that anything included in or set by a plugin will be available, because it's possible to disable the plugin while the theme is still active. Always include some sort of sanity check before attempting to access a variable, class or function from a plugin in your theme.

Edit: based on your discovery that the method you used has been deprecated, I'd suggest the following for your updated file:

```
if(isset($sitepress) && method_exists($sitepress, 'get_locale')) {
  setlocale(LC_TIME, $sitepress->get_locale(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) . '.UTF-8');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem!

$sitepress->locale() function was no longer available in new version of the wpml plugin. So a new update of WPML plugin broke the translation function.

```
global $sitepress;
setlocale(LC_TIME, $sitepress->get_locale(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) . '.UTF-8');
$_SESSION['date_format'] = (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr') ? 'le %e %B %G' : '%B %e, %G';
```

Comment: You should still check if $sitepress is available before using it for the reasons I outlined above.